# How to show multiple views fetching data

Tags: routes, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to display extra information on a specific entry when clicked, but retain on screen the other entries.

In these graphics, the gray represents "default" information about an entry, and red represents the "extended" information about an entry.

The "extended" information needs to fetch data before showing, so I can't use `v-if` or `active` class.

#### www.example.com/

[image]

#### www.example.com/1

[image]

#### www.example.com/3

[image]

I tried with multiple [named views](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-views.html), but doesn't do what expected, and seems like they are [not meant to do stuff like this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/302#issuecomment-166680219).

These is my simple code right now. I'm not sure where to go from here. Is [router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html)` an option?

```
const Entry = {
    template: '<div>Entry ID {{ $route.params.id }}</div>'
};

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/:id',
            component: Entry
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish.  You seem to be routing, but displaying the same information on identical urls.  What data should be displayed when and where?

Comment: The code sample is quite confusing. It shows that you actually only display one entry for the given route and not 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a parent component `Entries` that will be responsible for listing `Entry` components, and pass props to `Entry` indicating if it should fetch data. With [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) it would llook like this:

**Entries.vue**

```html
<template>
    <entry
        v-for="entry of entries"
        :fetchData="(entry.id === $route.params.id)"
        :entry="entry"
    ></entry>
</template>

<script>
    import Entry from './path/to/Entry.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            Entry,
        },

        data() {
            return {
                entries: [], // Array with entries data
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**Entry.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div>{{ entry }}</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['fetchData', 'entry'],

        mounted() {
            // do some fetching magic if this.fetchData === true
        }
    }
</script>
```

VueRouter should render `Entries` instead of `Entry`. If you wouldd like to fetch multiple `Entry` components, think about using `$route.query` instead of `$route.params.id`.